# Error en nuevo Proyecto web dinámico - archivo web.xml

Tags: jsp, java-ee

Me encuentro con un error que no soy capaz de solucionar, el caso es que después de hacer unos códigos de ejemplo y probarlos con el servidor Tomcat 10 que tengo instalado funcionan bien pero en el proyecto web dinamico, concretamente el archivo web.xml me da error, adjunto foto y código por si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, aunque he probado a cambiar j2ee por javaee y me sigue dando error la etiqueta .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>otro</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

He probado a poner 2.4 y desaparece el error en la linea 2 version="2.5" pero sigue con el error el archivo y además el error de  continua, muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos días he conseguido solucionar el problema tan solo sustituyendo en la línea 3 j2ee por javaee, eliminando así el error subrayado de la línea 2 -> 2.5 y el de la línea 6 -> .

Después he guardado los cambios y se han quitado los errores salvo en la línea 2 que seguía el típico circulo rojo con aspa blanca con el que no puedes solucionar nada, pero en esta ocasión he pulsado con el botón derecho sobre el proyecto y después Build Project, lo que ha solucionado por completo los errores en mi proyecto.

También he sustituido en la línea 5 -> web-app_2_4.xsd por web-app_2_5.xsd, ya que si copias esta dirección: https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd y la pegas en el navegador no te devuelve ninguna descarga del archivo xsd y te redirecciona a la página principal de Oracle: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/, sin embargo, cuando pegas la dirección: https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd sí que te devuelve la descarga del archivo xsd, solo por esta razón lo dejo así, pero ya digo que cuando cambié j2ee por javee dejo de dar error de sintaxis.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>otro</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda a alguien que le ocurra lo mismo, saludos a todos y ánimo que todo tiene solución.